# Como retornar um vetor em outro vetor em Java?

Tags: java, array, funções

Estou fazendo um programa que aplica subida de encosta, porém o valor que preciso comparar para saber se o anterior é melhor que o próximo é um vetor `double`

Meu método para achar o melhor valor retorna um vetor `double`:

```
public double[] método(parâmetros){

   código

   return vetor;

}
```

Oque não estou conseguindo fazer é atribuir esse vetor em um outro vetor:

```
public void método2(parâmetros){

   double vet2[] = new double[n];

   vet2[]=método(parâmetros);

}
```

Minha pergunta é como eu conseguiria retornar o vetor e passar os valores dele para outro vetor em outro metodo?

Comment: Se o melhor valor é apenas 1 porquê retornar um vetor double? E seria apenas `vet2 = método(parâmetros);`

Comment: Obrigado, é isto mesmo.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2):

Isto?

```
public double[] método(int n) {
    return new double[n];
}

public void método2(int n) {
   double vet2[] = método(n);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/ReturnObject.java).

Answer (score 1):

Você está tentando fazer o seguinte:

```
vet2[]=método(parâmetros);
```

É como se você estivesse tentando acessar uma posição nula do vet2.

Para associar um novo vetor à variável, basta o nome dela, sem os colchetes:

```
vet2=método(parâmetros);
```